# Pandas Array Length Does Not Match Index Length, Works Weekly but Not Monthly?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

The reason the code below is not working is driving me crazy and I'm hoping someone can help me please.

I have some functions that `.resample()` the time index of two data sets to merge and create the honey_adj_signals dataframe that is passed into the code below.
When I `.resample()` the indexes of the data sets with `'W'`this code works fine, but when I try `'M'` I get an 'array length 14 does not match index length 15' error as the output from the code.

I don't understand why this is happening nor how to correct, I'm stuck.

I've uploaded the weekly dataframe here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4xdnV0LFZI1TmRnZllVSW52aWs

And the monthly dataframe here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4xdnV0LFZI1WnBSWVBpMzR2MGM

```
honey_adj_long_profits = pd.DataFrame({
        "Price": honey_adj_signals.loc[(honey_adj_signals["Signal"] == "Buy") &
                                  honey_adj_signals["Regime"] == 1, "Price"],
        "Profit": pd.Series(honey_adj_signals["Price"] - honey_adj_signals["Price"].shift(1)).loc[
            honey_adj_signals.loc[(honey_adj_signals["Signal"].shift(1) == "Buy") & (honey_adj_signals["Regime"].shift(1) == 1)].index
        ].tolist(),
        "End Date": honey_adj_signals["Price"].loc[
            honey_adj_signals.loc[(honey_adj_signals["Signal"].shift(1) == "Buy") & (honey_adj_signals["Regime"].shift(1) == 1)].index
        ].index
    })
print(honey_adj_long_profits)
```

The final output should look like this (this is what the weekly output looks like)

```
             End Date       Price     Profit
2008-03-09 2008-04-13   78.154000  -0.326000
2008-04-20 2008-05-25   73.822002  -4.990003
2008-06-15 2008-06-29   75.564000 -11.630000
2008-07-20 2008-08-03   57.648001  13.965999
2008-08-31 2008-10-12   57.467999 -23.675999
2008-12-21 2009-01-04   33.970000  -0.047499
2009-01-18 2009-02-08   34.144000  -0.934001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to kick yourself when I tell you what is wrong.

In your weekly data your last records is a 'Sell' signal, the way you are processing this information is in pairs.  You get to the 'Buy' signal then you shift one to the 'Sell' record.

In your monthly data, your last record is a 'Buy' signal, therefore when you try to shift to the next 'Sell' record Index length error occurs.  To test this I removed the last record in your monthly data and ran your code.  Executes without error.

I think.

Comment: @Scott_Boston, kicked myself 2x over. Also added the following code before this so it is 'even' and executes:
`if honey_adj_signals.iloc[-1,2]== 'Buy': 
 honey_adj_signals = honey_adj_signals.head(n =(len(honey_adj_signals)-1))
else:
 honey_adj_signals = honey_adj_signals`

Comment: Very nice catch !